# 2 hard disk drives with ubuntu

Tags: disk

I've just downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and I've already installed it on 2 hard disk drives, however, I want to use one disk as an storage disk (160GB) and I want to use the other one for work (30GB).

How can I tell to the system that I want to initialize with the disk of 30 Gb and I want to left the other one (160GB) connected and using it as storage?

I would be very glad to receive any suggestions.

Comment: As Rinzwind said, you'll have to create and select the partitions manually.  I'd actually suggest that you use the 30Gb drive for / ("root") and the larger drive for /home.  If you want to keep work and data separate, do it by using separate folders in you home folder.  There are many advantages of having a completely separate /, but the main ones are that problems with / will not affect your data, you can re-install easily without formating /home, and if you do fill up the /home drive it won't crash the operating system because it has it's own space allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During install your are prompted on what to do. Choose 'manual configuration'. Select the 30Gb disc (probably called sdb1; but check the size for it being around 30Gb) and create partitions on that disc. One of these needs to be called `/`, you also 'need' a `swap` and preferably a `/home` and this will be used as the start up disc.

The 160 Gb disc you can mount with a mount point (example `/documents` or `/pluto`.) The system will create a directory inside the root system with that name where this disc is accessible (after you set the correct permissions) for you to store documents on.

---

Permissions (from terminal): `chown $USER:$USER /{mountpont}` Just change the {mountpoint} and the $USER will be dealt with by the system.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys!
Well I did the opposite thing. I used the 160GB disk as the start up disc and the other one (30GB) as storage but it works great even though whenever I want to save or create documents on it I have to create them on the terminal 'cuz I still have to set the correct permissions just as Rinzwind said. I'll fix the permissions stuff and I'll let you know. 
Thank you for your help again.

Comment: no problem @user119177 Ofcourse switching the discs does not matter. Don't forget to upvote and accept (the last one if there is no better answer ;) )

Comment: Sorry for being late. It worked fine! 
Thank you very much guys for your help.